# Wacom intuos button maping option not available

Tags: unity, mouse, configuration, wacom, button

I tested an intuos pen & touch tablet with ubuntu 14.10. But the configuration panel did not show the "Map Buttons..." button.

Thus, I am unable to map them, unless I use xsetwacom. But if I do that, I have both two buttons on the left side respectively from top to bottom button 3 and button 1.
When I type in button 2, it lets me configure it but it corresponds to nothing, and I did test many other numbers but I do not find how to configure the two buttons on the right side.

Any help is welcome :·)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a known bug. Have you tried the script in the last comment at http://sourceforge.net/p/linuxwacom/bugs/244/ ?

Comment: Thank you! It works! After running the script, I typed in: xsetwacom set 19 button [x] [keystroke] ,  with [x] equal to either 1 or 3 or 8 or 9 and [keystroke] the correspondent action. It is great! Thanks!