# Wacom Intuos 4 map buttons not remaining

Tags: unity, tablet, wacom

I use a Wacom Intuos 4 at work. My pen broke and ict delivered a new pen. But the wrong pen. An inking pen (number 7 in the Wacom settings panel) which has no buttons at all.

But I like the pen. It's easy, robust and better for drawing. But I cannot map mouse buttons and mouse wheel options to the buttons on the tablet itself.

So, after some searching, it turned out it's possible to use

```
xsetwacom
```

Ok, nice. So it took a while and was able to bind all I wanted (not necessarily to the most logical buttons, but that seems to be a [bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/567099/wacom-intuos-button-maping-option-not-available)).

Next boot: settings gone. Only the settings set in the Unity Settings Panel were still there. Odd. You can set 'Send Keystroke', 'None', 'Switch Monitor' or 'Show On-Screen Help'. With 'Send Keystrok' you cannot map mouse clicks or mouse wheel (which would be ideal for the ring..).

I could use the Wacom Settings panel from Unity *if* it were possible to set mouse clicks and scroll wheel functions.

That's not possible.

So, I was wondering, is there a way to see the configuration file from the Unity settings and/or which config file does it use? So I could set the settings straight into that file. I don't seem to be able to find it...

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to call your script that set buttons by hand or automatically every time you connect your tablet.

I have a script that I published in [Wacom button and mouse button setting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/729564/wacom-button-and-mouse-button-setting); to execute it automatically when the tablet is inserted:

drop in `/etc/udev/rules.d/` the file `99-wacom_local.rules`

with content:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="056a", ATTR{idProduct}=="0084", RUN+="/home/romano/software/scripts/wacom_set_xournal_auto"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="056a", ATTR{idProduct}=="0302", RUN+="/home/romano/software/scripts/wacom_set_xournal_auto"
```

...and fine-tune your codes for your tablet id, that you can obtain with `lsusb` (and obviously the path of your personalization script).

References here: http://www.techytalk.info/udev-rule-to-run-script-after-plugging-in-usb-device-on-ubuntu-linux-operating-system/

Yes, not user-friendly at all.